# \subimport is to \input or \include as what is to \RequirePackage?

Tags: import

As the title says, when writing a class or a package, is there a way to "`\RequirePackage`" using a path relative to "where the `.cls` or `.sty` file itself is", not "where the main `.tex` file is", just as the `\subimport` (from the `import` package) macro does for common `.tex` files?

For instance, a custom local package `a.sty` is required when writing a class `a.cls`, yet the class file `a.cls` is to be used by several `.tex` files at different paths.

Comment: Usually you would put your class file and your package files into a local TeXmf directory structure and then the path is irrelevant as they will be found by filename.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for your reply! I know I should do as you said, and indeed it is a best practice in most cases, but I just want to know if there is such an auxiliary package could achieve this goal. Actually, in my case, both class and package are planned to be updated frequently as a git submodule, which is to be used by several persons. So if there were no such a way, I should do as your advice.